# Operators with integrals defintion: $Q^*Q=Q?$

Tags: functional-analysis, adjoint-operators

> Definite two operators $Q,V$ on $E=L^2(0,1)$ as follow:
>
> for all $f\in E;$ $$(Qf)(x)=f(x)-\int_0^1 f(x)dx$$
>   $$(Vf)(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$$
>
> Now denote $A=QV$ and $T=A^*A$.

I would like to prove that $T=V^*A.$

We have that $T=(QV)^*QV=V^*Q^*QV.$ Which means I need to prove that $Q^*Q=Q.$

Now, $\langle \phi,Qf\rangle_{E,E}=\langle Q^*\phi,f\rangle_{E,E}$ as $E^*=E.$

If I am correct I have to prove that $\langle Qf,Qf\rangle=(Qf)(x),$ but $$\langle Qf,Qf\rangle=(Qf)(x)-\int_0^1 (Qf)(x)dx=f(x)-2\int_0^1f(x)dx-\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x)dxdx.$$

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x)dxdx=\int_0^1f(x)dx $$
Also the last term in your last equation should be positive. 
$$\langle Qf,Qf\rangle=(Qf)(x)-\int_0^1 (Qf)(x)dx=f(x)-2\int_0^1f(x)dx+\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x)dxdx.$$

Comment: silly my, yeah the first equality is trivial! arf, thanks!